# Using SFTP or SSH

Tags: ssh, sftp

If both SFTP and SSH both runs on same port `#22`. Then in which case do we need to use each of them separately.

Comment: It is not clear the question you're asking - this doesn't appear to be about security?

Answer (score 2):

SFTP is subsystem of SSH. When you run `sftp` command, it internally creates `ssh` connection for you and run `sftp-server` on the other side.

[SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (Secure SHell) itself is separately for remote shell. [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) (SSH File Transfer Protocol) itself separately is for file transfer, as you can make up from the shortcuts.